# Formula for series of Binomial Coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Farmer John's hobby of conducting high-energy physics experiments on weekends has backfired, causing N wormholes (2 <= N <= 12, N even) to materialize on his farm, each located at a distinct point on the 2D map of his farm (the x,y coordinates are both integers).

According to his calculations, Farmer John knows that his wormholes will form N/2 connected pairs. For example, if wormholes A and B are connected as a pair, then any object entering wormhole A will exit wormhole B moving in the same direction, and any object entering wormhole B will similarly exit from wormhole A moving in the same direction. This can have rather unpleasant consequences.

For example, suppose there are two paired wormholes A at (1,1) and B at (3,1), and that Bessie the cow starts from position (2,1) moving in the +x direction. Bessie will enter wormhole B [at (3,1)], exit from A [at (1,1)], then enter B again, and so on, getting trapped in an infinite cycle!

*So no: of possible pairs would be this C(n,2)*C(n-2,2)*C(n-4,2)*C(n-6,2)*C(n-8,2)*.......*

Sorry being so trivial,but i think there might be some kind of formula for this series
**C(n,2)*C(n-2,2)*C(n-4,2)*C(n-6,2)*C(n-8,2)*.......** like we have for C(n,2)+C(n-2,2)+C(n-4,2)+C(n-6,2)....=2^n-1

But i'am unable to arrive it,
if possible even suggest some kind of source for formulae for series of binomial coefficients

So what does this expression amount to

> C(n,2)*C(n-2,2)*C(n-4,2)*C(n-6,2)*C(n-8,2).......=E(n)

Comment: $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}$

$\binom{n-2}{2}=\frac{(n-2)!}{2!(n-4)!}$...
Can you see them cancel out? Try even and odd cases for $n$.

Comment: Take a look at Mathworld's page on [multinomial coefficients](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialCoefficient.html), and specifically consider the case of all $n_k$'s equal to 2 (say, by taking equation 3 and applying it over-and-over again).

Comment: @JonathanRichardLombardy  i never thought of expanding expression in that way thanks

Comment: @Semiclassical thanks i'll will look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we use the representation $\binom{n}{k}$ to denote the binomial coefficient $C(n,k)$. It is convenient to split the calculation in even and odd $n$.

> **Case:** $2n$
>
> We obtain for $n\geq 1$
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{2n}{2}&\binom{2n-2}{2}\cdots\binom{2}{2}=\prod_{k=1}^n\binom{2k}{2}=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k)!}{(2k-2)!2!}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^n}\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)!\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(2k-2)!}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^n}\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)!\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2k)!}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the product sign, multiply thereby the binomial coefficients from right $\binom{2}{2}$ to left $\binom{2n}{2}$ and use the definition
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
  \end{align*}
- In (2) we split the factors into single products and use $\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2!}=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2^n}$.
- In (3) we shift the index of the second product by one and observe that by telescoping all factors with $1\leq k \leq n-1$ cancel.

In the same way we can do the calculation for odd values.

> **Case:** $2n+1$
>
> We obtain for $n\geq 1$
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{2n+1}{2}&\binom{2n-1}{2}\cdots\binom{3}{2}=\prod_{k=1}^n\binom{2k+1}{2}=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k+1)!}{(2k-1)!2!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^n}\prod_{k=1}^n(2k+1)!\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(2k-1)!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^n}\prod_{k=1}^n(2k+1)!\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}\\
> &=\frac{(2n+1)!}{2^n}
> \end{align*}